Creating and managing a workspace for a different user in perforce
I have to perform a migration from TFS to P4. As a part of migration, any existing repositories on the user machines would transformed into P4 equivalents.
The idea is to move the files around to match the new folder structure, create a p4 workspace (client) in place (along with .p4config) and then run p4 sync -k to initialize it and make it ready for use.
The problem is, I won't be able to log into p4 as users whose workspace I'm working on. I'd have to log in as myself. If my user creates a workspace with them as the owner, I don't supposed they would run into any problems down the line if they then log in as themselves and start syncing and submitting as a part of their normal workflow?

Note that if you have super permissions in Perforce, you can get a login ticket for another user by doing:
p4 login USERNAME

That aside, there isn't any problem with another user using a client spec you created as long as it's not locked, but even so, you might want to set the Owner to the name of the user who'll be using the client, since it will make it easier to see what client is intended for each user.
If you're creating the client specs remotely, make sure to set the Host field to the correct client hostname -- and be careful with p4 sync -k since it needs to match whatever is already on that client machine or users will be unable to sync those files.
